# I am trying to create a function that allows an object to move down the screen

Tags: swift, skaction

I am trying to create a function that allows an object to move down the screen from top to bottom but I get this error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var b: UIButton!
    let getDuration=0
    let node=0
    let endpoint=0

    @IBAction func swipe(_ sender: UIButton) {
        func bpp(pointA:CGPoint,pointB:CGPoint,speed:CGFloat)->TimeInterval{
            let xd = (pointB.x - pointA.x)
            let yd = (pointB.y - pointA.x)
            let d = sqrt((xd*xd)+(yd*yd));
            let dur : TimeInterval=TimeInterval(d/speed)
            return dur
        }
    }

    lazy var m = SKAction.moveTo(endpoint, dur : getDuration(node.position,pointB:endpoint,speed:70.0))
}
```

Comment: Why did you declare your `bpp` function inside your `swipe` function?

Comment: Why are you trying treat your `getDuration` property like a function?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors. You define a function, `bpp(pointA: CGPoint, pointB: CGPoint, speed: CGFloat)` as a nested function inside your `swipe()` IBAction, and then never call it (or do **anything** inside your `swipe()` action. Then you have a line

```
lazy var m = SKAction.moveTo(endpoint, 
  dur: getDuration(node.position,pointB:endpoint,speed:70.0))
```

that is not inside any function that treats your Int variable `getDuration` as if it's a function. (That's almost certainly the line that is throwing an error.) I suspect you meant to have that line read.

```
lazy var m = SKAction.moveTo(endpoint, 
  dur: bpp(node.position,pointB:endpoint,speed:70.0))
```

Instead. (after pulling `bpp()` out of the Inaction and making it an instance method instead of a nested fuction of your `IBAction`.